# Why i can't print with a WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, printing

i copied and pasted  the code from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3.aspx), i don't know what is 'PrintDocument'
in that line:

```
webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);
```

i change it to 'printDocument1' but it tells me :

> printDocument1 is a 'field' but is used like a 'method'

in my form :

```
 - printPreviewControl1
 - printDocument1
 - pageSetupDialog1
```

Comment: `PrintDocument` is a method (function). `printDocument1` is a field (probably a control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also include the `PrintDocument()` method from that sample:

```
private void PrintDocument(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

    // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: now it says: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser'.

Comment: in that line: ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

Comment: Make sure the other part is still: `webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);`

Comment: I think you said you had tried changing that to pass a `PrintDocument` object (which you don't need at all in this example)

Comment: If you're new to Events in C#, you might want to start by reading up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx